# Is it safe to plug a transformer into a surge protector?

Tags: voltage, power, transformer

All my searches have come up with "DO NOT PLUG A SURGE PROTECTOR INTO A TRANSFORMER," but what I need to know is the opposite (if I can plug a transformer into a surge protector without issue).

What I want to do is plug a transformer into a surge protector and then take an output of 110V converted to 220V to power a 1.5kW spindle motor's VFD. Are there any issues doing this?

Comment: Maybe the inrush current is an issue, surge protectors don't like big inrush currents

Comment: what's the current rating of the surge protector? 1.5kW to a motor, through an (ideally) 80% efficient transformer can quickly push to 20+ Amperes draw & trip (or damage) your surge suppressor. Also, "inductor ringing" from the transformer could potentially raise the sensed voltage back to the surge protector above trip threshold, blowing the surge protector & "taking out" your circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that, the reason you shouldn't do it the other way is that you can turn the varistors into a conductor (by overvolting) creating a short circuit in the surge protector.

Answer (score 1):

VOltage surges in Africa from starting up an imbalanced 3Phase from surge current can wipe out all your appliances for example.

A direct lightning strike to the home power feed can wipe out even the best MOV.

> My point is,  surges must be defined as what surge you can expect and
>   what can your equipment withstand as per the equipment rating.

If you don't know, how can we guess?

Typically all the North America power meters have large conical metal punch size points across the line to catch any lightning surges >6kV not arrested by the distribution line surge arrestors.  There are various classes of immunity, guessing may offer ease of mind, but do little to protect your equipment.

Whatever you choose for Transient suppression must include a current breaker or fuse and preferable a line filter before the MOV to attenuate the surge.

The transformer must be properly sized to handle the current surges of the VFD and the power factor is used to derate the VA capacity plus some margin for good performance.

I see no issue with a properly sized transformer and a balanced network for split phase.  That assumption may be huge in India where so many DIY stabilizers are used due to unstable voltages which adds further load currents and makes the network even more unstable for voltage.

Answer (score -1):

**YES**

What do you think your phone charger is? A transformer followed by a rectifier and a voltage regulator. Any problems with plugging that into a surge protector?

In reality, this probably isn't such a great idea. At 110V, a 1.5 kW motor will draw 13.6 A, even at 100% efficiency. Add in a 80% efficient transformer, and now it's 17A. Check the ratings on your surge protector and transformer...

Comment: This answer seems a bit confused. OP is asking about a regular transformer - not a SMPS DC supply and nothing to do with phones.  Second paragraph is fine. Third paragraph sounds like you're discussing North American split-phase 110-0-110 which doesn't require 3-phase.

Comment: @dpdt, on the second paragraph -- if a house's circuit breaker trips, is that a good indication of wires being overheated? If that doesn't occur, is it safe to draw 17A+?

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for pointing out the mistake in the 3rd para - I rm'ed it. What I meant with the phone charger is to show that you **can and do plug in transformers safely**, (in this case, a transformer leading to a rectifier and a SMPS) so why not the one that the OP is talking about?

Comment: @dpdt: Phone charger: 1.5 W. OP's transformer: 1500 W. That's why. Also they're different technologies. Phone charger is switched-mode power supply - tiny transformer at high frequency. Power transformer is just copper windings on iron core and operates at mains frequencies.

Comment: @Shakurin NO! Your wires can *overheat and melt* if the wire gauge is not large enough (lower numbers = higher current capacity). 17A is a lot. Also, you would be wise to check your breaker rating - many are only 15A.